# How to plot values from atomic vectors (matrix) in R

Tags: r, plot

I am having a problem plotting and accessing the following matrix I have created.

Here I have created a version everyone may follow w/o my data.

```
a<-rnorm(10,0,1)
b<-rnorm(10,2,1)


J<-matrix(0,10,2)
colnames(J)<-c("a","b")
J[,1]<-a
J[,2]<-b
```

And then wish to plot. but I get error messages I do not understand:

```
with(J,plot(a,b))
```

*+Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
 + numeric 'envir' arg not of length one*

with

```
plot(J$a,J$b)
```

*+plot(J$a,J$b)
+Error in J$a: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors*

Does anyone have any idea?

Kind Regards from GER

Comment: should  the line `(J,plot(a,b))`  really say `with(J, plot(a,b))` (which would still be incorrect)

Comment: yes. it should. i tried both versions.
1. with(J, plot(a,b))
2. plot(J$a,J$b)
I hadn't realised it doesn't work with matrices

I had taken an example from M.Crawley's The R book. However never noticed it has to be data.frames.

Comment: SOLVED:
I now have merely added:
J1<- as.data.frame(J)
with(J1,plot(a,b,))

works fine!

Thx also for the other answers. helped me, too.

Comment: if the answers were useful, then it is [SO etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to upvote those which are useful and to *accept* the  one which best answers your question

Answer (score 2):

It would work if J were defined as a data.frame, with columns a and b:

```
a<-rnorm(10,0,1)
b<-rnorm(10,2,1)

J <- data.frame(a,b)
with(J,plot(a,b))
```

$ only works with list objects (including data.frame). If you stick with the matrix, then you grab from the columns using brackets with indices or names:

```
J <- cbind(a,b)
plot(J,[,1],J[,2])
plot(J[,"a"],J[,"b"])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, were you have  a 2 column matrix `J`

```
plot(J)
```

will work as will

```
 plot(J[,'a'], J[,'b'])
```

The `` `$` `` operator is not defined for matrices, but is for `lists` or `data.frames`

`with` will not work with matrices because a matrix cannot be an environment or an enclosure

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(J[,1], J[,2])
```

and

```
with(as.data.frame(J), plot(a,b))
```

both work

Comment: this does infact have what I really, really thought of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the columns of a matrix by their names:

```
plot(J[ , colnames(J) %in% c("a", "b")])
```